# Package is in valid. Details: 'Could not unzip extension'

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Yesterday while trying to download another test version of my extension from Chrome web store, which had changes only in version number, I suddenly started to receive a strange error "Manifest file is invalid". I've spent all day searching the web for an answer to this problem, but didn't found anything useful.

Starting from this days morning error message had changed to:
"Package is in valid. Details: 'Could not unzip extension'"

I've already tried thous variants:

1. zipping it with folder and without a folder
2. shortening zip file name
3. zipping it on mac and on windows
4. verifying zip file
5. uploding it with compression and without compression
6. searching for non-utf characters

Seems like chrome just throws thous errors randomly no matter what.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension - Invalid Package. Details:Can't unzip the extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984320/chrome-extension-invalid-package-detailscant-unzip-the-extension)

Comment: for "manifest file is invalid" you should wait few minutes after uploading. For the "could not unzip extension" try to see my answer of possible duplicated question

Comment: Already saw it and did as u said - error message still appears..

Comment: When chrome says "Manifest file is invalid" you should simply wait some minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed - try re-uploading and publishing again. Make sure to bump up your version number.